# Can't render JSON in Ansible and post via uri module

Tags: json, ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible 1.9.4 to post a JSON body, but nothing works.

Here's what I have as one of the tasks:

```
- name: Post
  uri:
    url: https://hooks.slack.com/endpoint
    method: POST
    return_content: no
    HEADER_Content-Type: "application/json"
    body: "{{ lookup('template', '../templates/my.json.j2', convert_data=False) }}"
```

This always results in a `TypeError: unhashable type` error. I've tried the following in that JSON file and neither works:

```
{"channel": "chatops","username": "Deploy","text": "TEST Deploy!","icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}
```

and

```
{
  "channel": "chatops",
  "username": "Deploy",
  "text": "TEST Deploy!",
  "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"
}
```

However, putting the following in the play works:

```
body: '{"channel": "chatops-test","username": "Deploy","text": "TEST Deploy!","icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}'
```

Piping the `lookup` through `to_json` doesn't work either. And having a var set as the following and doing `body: "{{ the_body }}"` also does not work:

```
the_body:
  channel: "chatops-test"
  username: "Deploy"
  text: "TEST!!!"
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be running into a bug here.  I just spent some time running through a number of tests and keep running into unexpected issues, also using ansible 1.9.4. Here's a quick rundown of where I'm currently at with regards to your issue:

```
   - name: set fact
      set_fact: foo="{{ lookup('template', 'oneline.txt', convert_data=False) }}"

    - debug: var=foo

    - name: echo foo
      shell: echo '{{ foo }}' > /tmp/foo.out
```

The file 'oneline.txt' has your json string:

```
{"channel": "chatops","username": "Deploy","text": "TEST Deploy!","icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}
```

The output of this shows that Ansible is truncating the string in an odd way:

```
PLAY [test] *******************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [set fact] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [debug var=foo] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "foo": "\"{\"channel\": \"chatops\",\"username\": \"Deploy\",\"text\": \"TEST"
    }
}

TASK: [echo foo] **************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

The file '/tmp/foo.out' is also showing the truncated value:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.out
"{"channel": "chatops","username": "Deploy","text": "TEST
```

On top of all this, if you remove the bounding quotes from the `set_fact` call then the string is truncated even more.

I'd recommend either posting a question about this to the [Ansible project forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ansible-project) and/or submitting a bug report to [Ansible on github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues).  The Ansible developers monitor both of these on a regular basis so they'd likely be able to confirm what's going on and hopefully address it if they believe it's a bug.